# Omnsharp's Intellisense not working

Tags: c#, intellisense, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I'm on Windows 8.1, using VS Code 1.0.0 and C# for VS Code version 1.0.1-rc2.

The problem is that I can't get Intellisense to work when opening C# projects, but when developing extensions, I do have intellisense enabled.

[image: Working for extensions...]

[image: Not working on C#]

One thing though, is that when VS Code opens, Omnisharp starts...but, there is an error:

> [INFO] Starting OmniSharp at 'c:\dev\TestI'... [ERROR]
>   Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.30.252.126:443

This is my project.json file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002392"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {}
  }
}
```

I also have **"http.proxy"** set up already.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone has the same problem. Altough it doesn't seem to be a proxy problem there are manual steps to solve the issue.

Go to, https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/releases/ and download the version of omnisharp you need. Unpack it, add a new item in the VS Code preferences: "csharp.omnisharp": "path/to/where/you/unpacked/the/files/".

Restart VS Code.

Taken from: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/200

Answer (score 0):

First,you should download omnisharp-win-x64-netcoreapp1.0.zip  from https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/releases， then unzip to C:\tmp\omnisharp-win-x64-netcoreapp1.0.You will get file C:\tmp\omnisharp-win-x64-netcoreapp1.0\OmniSharp.exe。

setting vscode config for c# Intellisense prompt。

Open vscode menu “File ”->"Option”->"setting", you can edit file settings.json.Add newLine

go to:http://www.freemanwoman.com/running-c-aspnet-core-rc2-in-visual-studio-code-with-the-latest-omnisharp-plugin